# Copy construction in OCaml?

Tags: reference, copy, ocaml

OCaml values are passed by reference as opposed by value. When the values are constant, there is no observable difference between references and values. However, when the value is mutable (such as a struct with mutable fields), I may want to copy it such that when one variable mutates the value, another variable that was set to the former variable is not mutated as well. Can I do this in OCaml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid there is no automatic easy way for it.  You have to make a copy of a value by writing some code by yourself.  For example,

```
type t = { x : int option; mutable y : int option }

let copy t = { t with x = t.x }

let () =
  let t = { x = None; y = Some 1 } in
  let t' = copy t in
  t.y <- None;
  assert (t'.y <> None) (* check t'.y is not shared *)
```

There are also `copy` functions for primitive mutable types, such as `Bytes.copy` and `Array.copy`.

If your value is nested then your copy function may or may not take care of the copying of the internal values.

There is a magical function `Obj.dup` which creates a deep copy of an argument, but I believe you will not want to use it, since it duplicates all the value nodes recursively, including the immutables, which is very bad for the space efficiency.

Comment: Thanks! In the with construct, do the fields of the copied value point to the same places on the heap or are they guaranteed to reference something else? If so, is the 'x = t.x' step an optimization to make the immutable fields point to the same heap location?

Comment: Are you sure Obj.dup is recursive? There's no documentation and the code in caml_obj_dup in obj.c seems not to be recursive.

Answer (score 4):

There are three syntactical ways to introduce mutable values:

- define a record with a mutable field;
- use some predefined mutable container, such as Array, Bytes, Bigarray;
- define a class with a mutable field.

## One function to `clone` them all

There is no such function, that will take any value and will return a clone of it unless you're willing to rely on the unsafe `Obj` module, or to use the `Marshal` module. So in pure OCaml, it's not possible to get a bitwise copy of another value, since OCaml is trying to abstract its binary representation from an application. If you really need then the following inefficient implementation may suffice your needs:

```
   let clone (type t) (x : t) : t = 
     let buf = Marshal.(to_bytes x [No_sharing; Closures]) in
     Marshal.from_bytes buf 0
```

It will not work with values that do not support marshaling, for example with file descriptors, and with custom objects (implemented in C) that doesn't implement the marshaling interface.

### Mutable records

There is no base type to which all records belong. So, for each record with a mutable type, you need to provide your own cloner, or you can rely on the `clone` function above.

### Predefined containers

All predefined containers provide the clone function, however, since they all belong to different types, there is no generic function, that will handle them all.

### Mutable objects

Object-oriented programming was always tightly connected with mutability. Thus OCaml provides the `Oo.copy` function that works on all objects since there is an object type `<..>` to which all other objects belong. So, if you indeed need a generic clone function, then consider using objects.